# union of sigma algebra is sigma algebra

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

I need help to demonstrate:

Let  $F,G$  two $\sigma$-algebra in $\Omega$, if $F\cup G$ is $\sigma$-algebra in $\Omega$, show $F\subset G$ or $G\subset F$.

Thanks

Comment: Notice that union of two (or more) $\sigma$-algebra not always is a $\sigma$-algebra

Comment: Notice, si $F\subset G$ or $G\subset F$ is true

Comment: @LuísaBorsato , You are right.The union of two (or more) σ-algebra is not always a σ-algebra. However, this question is about the necessary (and sufficient) condition for the union of two σ-algebra to be a σ-algebra. See the answer I have posted.

Comment: The answer below, at the moment, is wrong. There is a correct answer in [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3448995/713897)

Answer (score 5):

Assume not. Then there exists $f\in F$ and $g\in G$ such that neither is in the other set. Since $F\cup G$ is a $\sigma$-algebra, $f\cup g$ is in it. Thus it's in at least one of $F$ and $G$. If $f\cup g$ is in $F$, then $$g=g\cap (f\cup g)\in F$$ gives a contradiction. Likewise If $f\cup g$ is in $G$, then $$f=f\cap (f\cup g)\in F$$ gives a contradiction.

Comment: $g\cap (f\cap g)\in F$ You Can not Secure