# Union of sigma algebras is sigma algebra iff one of them contains the other

Tags: measure-theory

How would one prove the following? Let $F$ and $G$ be $\sigma$-algebras on $\Omega \neq \emptyset$. Then, $F \cup G$ is a $\sigma$-algebra iff $F \subset G$ or $G \subset F$.

One implication is obvious, but the other one.. I have no clue where to even start.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Note that the only answer there at the moment is not correct.

Comment: Why is it not correct @conditionalMethod

Comment: The wrong part of it at the moment is that the poster writes $g=g\cap (f\cup g)$, but then you're proving that $g\in F\Longrightarrow g\in F$. By assumption $g\not \in F,$ so doing operations with $g$ doesn't give you anything,.

Answer (score 3):

Well, you have to ask yourself: What could go wrong? Clearly, if $A\in F\cup G,$ then $A^c\in F\cup G$, so the only thing that can fail is closure under countable unions. However, as it turns out, we only need finite unions:

Assume $A\in F\setminus G$ and $B\in G\setminus F$. Assume, without loss of generality, that $A\cup B\in F$. Then, $B\setminus A=(A\cup B)\cap A^c\in F$. Assume furthermore that $F\cup G$ is a $\sigma$-algebra.

Then, $A\cap B$, $A\cap B^c \in F\cup G$. Now, if $A\cap B\in F$, then $B= (B\setminus A) \cup (A\cap B)\in F,$ which is a contradiction. If $A\cap B\in G$ and $A\cup B^c$ in $F$, we get, reapplying the above that $A\cap B=(A\cap B)\setminus (A\cap B^c)\in F,$ which is, again a contradiction. Lastly, if $A\cap B\in G$ and $A\cap B^c\in G$, then $A= (A\cap B)\cup (A\cap B^c)\in G,$ which is a final contradiction.

Comment: Note that $(A\cup B)\cap A^c\subset B$ but not always equal. The argument can be fixed if you choose $A$ and $B$ disjoint. You need to show that you can do so. For that look at $A\cap B$ which should also be in $F\cup G$. Assume that $A\cap B\in F$. Then $A'=A\cap (A\cap B)^c\in F$, $A'\cap B=\emptyset$, and $A'\cup B=A\cup B\in F\cup G$. Similarly pass to a $B'$ if $A\cap B\in G$.

Comment: I agree that the above was naïve. The current argument should stand, though.